# Extendable tab with Typescript and Angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have simple tab using `<td></td>` in Angular 4 project who's returning me parsing data from a Json. I would like the tab extend himself dynamically until 10 lines (height) and then if I have more than 10 lines it dynamically add a scroll bar on the right side of the tab. I have initially 4 lines according to the 4 Json objects but it could increase depending on the datas quantity returning from the API. If anyone got ideas..thanks in advance

here's one line of my actual html table:

```
      <table>
      <tr>
             <td *ngFor="let user2 of userService2.users2 | async">
                    <span *ngIf="user2?.data.details[3].elt_state_id === 1">
                        <img src="./assets/img/icones_sized/cloud_small.png"/>
                    </span>
                    <span *ngIf="user2?.data.details[3].elt_state_id > 1">
                        <img src="./assets/img/icones_sized/storm_small.png"/>
                    </span>
                    <span *ngIf="user2?.data.details[3].elt_state_id < 1">
                        <img src="./assets/img/icones_sized/sun_small.png"/>
                    </span>
                <span [style.color]="['black', 'orange', 'red'][user2?.data.details[3].state_id]">{{user2.data.details[3].elt_label}}
                </span>
            </td>
            <td *ngFor="let user2 of userService2.users2 | async">{{user2.data.details[3].elt_type_label}}</td>
            <td *ngFor="let user2 of userService2.users2 | async">{{user2.data.details[3].elt_state}}</td>
            <td *ngFor="let user2 of userService2.users2 | async">{{user2.data.details[3].elt_since}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use this code with fixed styles, then you can solve this problem using only CSS. In that case you have to add `max-height` that will fit only 10 lines and `overflow-y: scroll`. So if you will have more than 10 lines scroll will appear.

Comment: Here you can see simple example of what I mean: https://plnkr.co/edit/Lv86Z6tJKs2iipGixmuE?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your help I'll try this out tomorrow morning